# what is the difference between bagging and boosting in random forest?

Tags: random-forest, boosting, bagging

I understand what is bagging and how it is applied to random forest. But how is bagging different from boosting. If boosting is different from bagging, how can boosting be applied to random forest?

Comment: Check out James et al. ["An Introduction to Statistical Learning"](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Fourth%20Printing.pdf) section 8.2, it's written quite clearly.

Comment: @rapaio oh!! sorry I didnt check it out.